# Understanding memory allocation in numpy: Is "temporary" memory being allocated when storing the result of an operation into variable[:, :]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, memory-management

Let's assume two **large** multidimensional numpy arrays `a` and `b`. I want to perform an element-wise operation, e.g. adding them element by element:

```
c = a + b
```

In the above case, new memory is allocated for the result of `a + b`. A reference to this memory is then stored in `c`.

Now, let's assume that memory for `c` has already been allocated. Setting the number of dimensions to two for the purpose of having a simple example, I can do the following:

```
c[:, :] = a + b
```

I can not find any documentation on how the above is exactly implemented. I can imagine two ways:

1. First, memory is allocated for performing the operation `a + b`. The result is stored into this "temporary" memory before the data i.e. the result of the operation is copied into `c[:, :]`.
2. There is no allocation of temporary memory. The result of `a + b` goes directly into `c[:, :]`.

I played around with some code and - I could be absolutely wrong here - performance-wise it feels like the first option is more likely. Am I right? If so, how could I avoid the allocation of "temporary memory" and directly store the result into the memory which is already available in `c`? I'd guess that I have to be more explicit, use functions like `numpy.add` and provide references to the target memory to them.

Comment: It's the first one because of how Python evaluates left-to-right... while numpy can do some fancy stuff, it can't override the mechanics of how Python evaluates statements...

Comment: @JonClements Yes, I guessed so ... I would not know how to implement `__add__` in another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operation you're looking for is

```
numpy.add(a, b, out=c)
```

With `c[:, :] = a + b`, the evaluation of `a + b` does not have information about the fact that the result will be assigned to `c[:, :]`. It must allocate a new array to hold the result of `a + b`.

(Recent versions of NumPy do try to perform some [C-level stack inspection](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/release.html#temporary-elision) to aggressively optimize temporaries beyond what the Python execution model would normally allow, but those optimizations don't handle this case. You can see the code in [`temp_elide.c`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/temp_elide.c), including some notes about what platforms it works on and why Python stack inspection isn't enough.)

Comment: Yup... the object on the RHS has no idea what it's being bound to (if it's being bound at all), so the only way to do it is like you say here using `numpy.add(a, b, out=c)` where it's explicitly given some space it can work in without having to make the presumption it has to build its own array for the result. (I tend to think of it like using C's `memcpy` kind of thing vs... a `malloc` operation)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this makes sense. I was simply wondering whether (or not) there is some black Python magic that I was not aware of :)

Comment: Expressions like `np.add(A[:,1:],A[:,:-1],out=A[:,1:])` suggest, though, that even with an `out`, `numpy` creates a temporary buffer.

Comment: @hpaulj: NumPy only makes copies for such an operation if it thinks a copy is necessary to handle overlapping input and output. For something like `add(a, b, out=c)` with no overlap, it won't make a copy. (The safety copies were [introduced](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#ufunc-behavior-for-overlapping-inputs) in NumPy 1.13.0.)